# Is there a way I can query a specific queue which is part of a larger queue in SQS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have a process which reads a message from SQS and process it. Each message has a `group_message_key`, and the processing of each message is relatively fast, but if I read a message with a different `group_message_key`, there is an extra processing time. Therefore I try to group the messages in order to avoid having these context switches.

I would like to have the option to initially read from a general queue, where all the messages are queued, and only after i have read the first message, query the message queue to deliver only messages with the specific `group_message_key`.

I am currently using Amazon SQS, but I don't mind at all changing to other message broker which can provide the feature I am missing (ie: Rabbit, Kafka).

I read from the same queue in parallel from many different processes so the solution would still need to support this. Amazon SQS has a FIFO queue which although it doesn't allow requesting messages with a specific `group_message_key`, it does tries to group these messages together, the problem is that it doesn't allow many workers to process the same message_group_id

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you are referring to the [Amazon SQS Message Group ID](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/using-messagegroupid-property.html).

This Message Group ID is unique to FIFO queues and ensures that messages with the same Message Group ID are always processed in-order.

To provide an example, imagine a number of buses sending their GPS coordinates to an Amazon SQS queue. A queue consumer wishes to retrieve these coordinates from the queue and plot the path of each bus on a map. It is important to always retrieve messages from a specific bus in the order that the messages were sent, but messages from multiple buses can also be processed.

This need can be accomplished by having each bus send a unique ID in the Message Group ID when sending its coordinates. When a consumer pulls a message from the queue, no further messages with the same Message Group ID will be provided to a queue consumer until this particular message has been processed. This ensures that the messages from a given bus are never processed out-of-order.

However, **it is *not* possible to request messages with a specific Message Group ID**. If your request to receive message from the queue indicates that you are willing to receive a Batch of messages, then multiple messages with the same Message Group ID *might* be provided.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said. I am asking if there is some other message broker which I do not know which might provide this feature.